# JavaFX WebEngine get HTTP response codes

Tags: java, javafx, urlconnection, javafx-webengine

I am trying to use the JavaFX WebEngine to access a website. To work properly, my application needs to know the http response code returned by the website and preferably also the response message. Is there a way to access this data over the WebEngine object? If not, is there a way to somehow intercept the used underlying URLConnection object if there is one?

Comment: Send a Head request to the URL first, inspect headers and then load URL to webengine.